# JavaScript's control flow constructs: browser specific or inherent to JS

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, variable-assignment, logical-operators

I've put together a little `range` function in JS. I've tested it in Chrome 19, FF, and IE (7-9) and it's working well. The question I have has to do with the `while` statement.

```
function range(from,to,step)
{
    'use strict';
    var sCode,eCode,result;
    result = [];
    step = (!step || isNaN(step) || step === 0 ? 1 : step);
    sCode = (''+from).charCodeAt(0);
    eCode = (''+to).charCodeAt(0);
    step *= (sCode > eCode && step > 0 ? -1 : 1);
    do
    {
        if (String.fromCharCode(sCode))
        {
            result.push(String.fromCharCode(sCode));
        }
    }while((step > 0 && eCode >= (sCode+=step)) || (step < 0 && eCode <= (sCode+=step)));
    return result;
}
```

I remember reading a question here a while back on how JS handles Control flow constructs and logical operators. I think it had something to do with checking if an object had a certain method, and if so, using it's return value (`if (event.returnValue && e.returnValue === true)` kind of stuff).
I can't seem to find that question any more, here's what I wanted to know:

```
while((step > 0 && eCode >= (sCode+=step)) || (step < 0 && eCode <= (sCode+=step)));
```

Since the function behaves as I want it to, I think I'm right in saying that, if `step < 0` is false, `&& eCode >= (sCode+=step)` will be ignored, leaving the value of `sCode` unchanged. 
When the `step` check is true, `sCode` will be in/decremented. I've put this assignment in brackets, to make sure that the newly assigned value of `sCode` will be compared to `eCode`. Again, I assume that the brackets will give priority to the assignment over the logical operator.

Is this true for *ALL* browsers, or is it browser specific to some extent? is there a chance that this function will increment (or decrement) the value of `sCode` twice in some browsers?
In this case, it's not that important (it's an easy fix to prevent any issues). But I want to know if this behaviour is inherent to JavaScript itself, or to the browser implementation.

---

Thanks for reading this far down. If you don't mind
A couple of other things (not important, but just wondering):

- what is the max charCode in JavaScript? A quick look on google didn't tell me, and testing in the JS console lead me to believe this was `5999999999989759` which seems almost incredible, but then again I might need to brush up on my Chinese.
- When `from` is undefined, the (jslint approved) approach `from.toString().charCodeAt(0);` fails, because obviously, `undefined` had no `toString` method, why the, does `(''+from).charCodeAt(0);` return `U` all the same? I thought it implicitly called the `toString` method?

Comment: "in saying that, if `step < 0` is false..." I think you meant `step < 0` Editing my comment: BRILLIANT question. I ran into issues/troubles with this (maybe I posted the original question you mentioned). I recall doing a _lot_ of testing. I'm going to see if I can find this info in the JS spec.

Comment: @taz, no... I'm sorry, but I have a hard time focussing on fridays: I meant that, when the first part of the logical check (being `step < 0`) _evaluates to false_, the second part `eCode >= ...` will be ignored. Example with values `while( (-1 > 0 && 3 >= (15+=-1)) || ...` the part `&& 3 >= (15+=-1)` will be ignored, since `-1 > 0` is false anyhow

Comment: I don't actually see any specs for short circuit evaluation (see http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11) I recall a few years ago thinking I found a situation in which this behavior was not consistent across browsers but I don't remember what the outcome was.

Comment: @taz: I did some more digging: as it turns out (sources [here](http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) JavaScript has no eager operators, only short circuits so I wouldn't know when you might have encountered inconsistent behaviour, but I got and bookmarked the ecmascript standard document for future reference. As far as I'm concerned, I've got my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I'm right in saying that, if `step < 0` is false, `&& eCode >=
>   (sCode+=step)` will be ignored, leaving the value of `sCode` unchanged

Correct. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second operand will not be evaluated.

> After when the step check is true, sCode will be in/decremented. I've
>   but this assignment in brackets, to be sure that the newly assigned
>   value of sCode will be compared to eCode. Again, I assume that the
>   brackets will give priority to the assignment over the logical
>   operator.

Correct again, but the parentheses around the assignment are required, since assignment has a [lower precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than a comparison.

> Is this true for ALL browsers?

Yes. I would be incredibly suprised if you find one that doesn't behave this way.

> When `from` is undefined, the (jslint approved) approach
>   `from.toString().charCodeAt(0);` fails, because obviously, undefined had
>   no `toString` method, why the, does `(''+from).charCodeAt(0);` return U
>   all the same?

Because it concatenates the value of `from` with the empty string. The value of `from` is `undefined`, which is [coerced to a string](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8), and you end up with the string "undefined", and the character at index 0 of that string is "u".

Comment: Thanks James. However, on that side note of concatenating `from`: the value of from is undefined, and has no `toString` method, yet it's value is converted to a string. I guess it's just one of those JS quirks, I sort of expect an undefined/uninitialized variable to behave as `null`, and return an empty string when it's converted to one.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - The `undefined` type is converted to the string "undefined". That's just the way it is. See the link to the spec: http://es5.github.com/#x9.8

Comment: I know this, but the link you provided shows all the results of a `ToString` operation. I merely remarked on the fact that it's strange that they don't provide the method to a value that can be converted to a string using a (slightly ugly) workaround. I'm even tempted to call it a hack, to be honest

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of operators is consistent for all correct implementations of ECMAScript. I'm not aware of any browser implementation that deviates from what you've described.

ECMAScript is defined by standard. http://ecmascript.org/

And yes, the parentheses will define associativity of the operators..

- [MDN Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Is there a specific place the ECMAScript mentions this?

Comment: I was referring to short circuit evaluation

Comment: @taz: Yes, the behavior of operators is fully described by ECMAScript. http://es5.github.com/#x11.11